# Snap binary override by binary placed in /snap/bin

Tags: firefox, snap, ubuntu-core, binary, snap-store

I moved a `geckodriver` binary to the `/snap/bin` directory. Now, after a reboot, my snap binary isn't working, and it seems that the `geckodriver` override the binary.

Now with more details: 
Basically I was coding with Selenium and had to install the `geckodriver` in order to use it on firefox. The problem was that my OS is Ubuntu 22.04, therefore, the firefox is installed as a snap package, and for this reason my program wasn't working because it couldn't find the `geckodriver`,then I moved the geckodriver binary to the `/snap/bin` directory. After I reboot the system my firefox wansnt working anymore, and neither the snap binary. I try to use the snap in terminal and what appers to be is that is running the `geckodriver` binary. Is there a way to fix this? My plan B is to reinstall my snap but I'm afraid that this could break the system.

Some evidences:

- When i execute the `snap` binary inside the `/bin` and `/usr/bin` their output is from `geckodriver`
- I checked the `sudo journalctl --no-pager -u snapd` and nothing had caught my attention
- I already removed the `geckodriver` from `/snap/bin` and reboot, but it didn't worked :(

Comment: The "binaries" in `/snap/bin` are all links to the snap command, iirc. Just reinstall snap.

Comment: They are all symliks to the `/usr/bin/snap` is that correct? If I reinstall i will loose my config of firefox?

Comment: No, reinstalling just snap itself will be just like upgrading it - all your data should be preserved.

Comment: Thx a lot, that worked